# Read file from 100th byte

Tags: winapi

How can I read a file from 100th byte, using `ReadFile` function and C++

I used this code but it reads the first 100 bytes of the file

I want to read the second 100 bytes

```
hndl = CreateFileW(L"1.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
SetFilePointer(hndl, 100, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
ReadFile(hndl, pbytReadBuffer, 100, NULL, &ol);
```

Comment: Why are you passing an `OVERLAPPED` structure to `ReadFile`? Change `&ol` to `NULL`.

Comment: The logic of the code you've sketched out here looks correct to me. You've seeked to the correct location, and then executed a read from that point. Of course, you aren't checking any return values, so you have no idea if any of these functions are failing. It is also concerning that you're passing an `OVERLAPPED` structure to `ReadFile`, despite the fact that you did not open the file handle with the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` option.

Comment: @CodyGray - `OVERLAPPED` can be used not only with the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED ` but for set offset for read/write operation - so use `OVERLAPPED` is absolute correct, another task - are it correct initialized ?

Comment: Indeed you can, but then there would be no point in calling SetFilePointer. Either way will work, but not both. SetFilePointer is conceptually simpler, especially for a one-off read in the middle of the file.

Comment: @CodyGray I check the return values, the values were ok, but the code doesn't do what I want

Comment: @CodyGray - of course when we use direct offset we not need use `SetFilePointer`. and this is much more effective - we can skip additional call to kernel mode

Comment: You don't check the return values. Read the code in the question one more time. The return values are ignored. Please don't tell me that your code is different from this.

Comment: As for how to read the file in chunks, as per your original (now deleted) question, you don't need to set the pointer. You read the first 100 bytes, not overlapped, and the pointer is advanced to 100. Then read the next 100 bytes, pointer advanced to 200 and so on. Please don't ignore return values. Please don't post fake code. Please slow down. Please read this: [mcve].

Answer (score 7):

The [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx) API offers two distinct ways to set the starting offset when doing synchronous I/O:

- By using the implicitly stored file pointer (which can be manipulated through the [SetFilePointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx) API call).
- Or by passing an explicit offset through the [OVERLAPPED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342.aspx) structure.

Your code fails because you are setting the implicitly stored file pointer, but then (presumably) pass a zero-initialized `OVERLAPPED` structure, which ignores the file pointer (see [Synchronization and File Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx#synchronization_and_file_position) for more information).

Either of the following solutions will work. First, by using the implicitly stored file pointer. This is useful, when you want to read chunks of a file in consecutive calls:

```
hndl = CreateFileW(L"1.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, nullptr,
                   OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
// Move the file pointer to offset 100
SetFilePointer(hndl, 100, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
// Read contents from the current offset
DWORD dwBytesRead{0};
ReadFile(hndl, pbytReadBuffer, 100, &dwBytesRead, nullptr);
```

Alternatively, you can pass an `OVERLAPPED` structure to pass the offset. This ignores the implicitly stored file pointer. It is slightly more efficient, because it doesn't need two calls to the file I/O API.

```
hndl = CreateFileW(L"1.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, nullptr,
                   OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
OVERLAPPED ol{};
// Set the offset from the start of the file
ol.Offset = 100;
ReadFile(hndl, pbytReadBuffer, 100, nullptr, &ol);
```

Note that error handling is elided in these samples for brevity. In real code, you always must check for errors.

Comment: implicitly stored file pointer can be used only in case synchronous I/O - when file created without `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`

Answer (score -1):

you need code like this

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    OVERLAPPED ov = {};
    ov.Offset = 100;
    UCHAR buf[100];
    ULONG cb;
    if (ReadFile(hFile, buf, sizeof(buf), &cb, &ov))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        GetLastError();
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

you not need call `SetFilePointer` - much better set offset direct in OVERLAPPED structure

**EDIT**

for every read/write operation we need to specify the starting byte offset. we can do this directed by setting values in `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` from OVERLAPPED.

or indirect **only if file opened if synchronous mode** -  I/O Manager can use the current file position in [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx) - so we can not direct set offset - it will be get from `FILE_OBJECT.CurrentByteOffset`.  `FILE_OBJECT.CurrentByteOffset` we can set with `SetFilePointer` also every read/write operation update this offset - move forward to count of bytes which readed/ written. of course this is correct only if file used in synchronous mode when all operations with file is sequential

if we use direct offset in `OVERLAPPED` he and used - so `FILE_OBJECT.CurrentByteOffset` is ignored - this mean that previous call to `SetFilePointer` - also lost all effect - will be used `offset` from `OVERLAPPED` and after read operation `FILE_OBJECT.CurrentByteOffset` will be updated based on offset + bytes readed

Comment: This might work, but it still does not explain why the call to `SetFilePointer` would fail.

Comment: @Cyclone - for what you use SetFilePointer and I can not know fail it in your code or not.

Comment: No, he doesn't want overlapped access at all

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - but I not say about overlapped access!! are you don't know that `OVERLAPPED` used not only for this ?!

Comment: @Cyclone: The call to `SetFilePointer` succeeds, but its effect is ignored, when passing an explicit offset through the `OVERLAPPED` structure. The offset is relative to the start of the file (see [Synchronization and File Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx#synchronization_and_file_position)).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: An `OVERLAPPED` structure can be used in a call to `ReadFile` for synchronous reads as well.

Comment: @RbMm OK, I misspoke. But still, this is a total novice. He wants to pass `NULL` and concentrate on the basics. Like error checking. In fact he actually wants to read the file sequentially in small chunks (as per previous deleted question) and so has no need for explicitly setting the file pointer at all. Recommending use of `OVERLAPPED` to specify a file pointer that doesn't need to be specified isn't helpful to this user.

Comment: *for every read/write operation we need to specify the starting byte offset*  No. The file pointer is advanced by previous reads/writes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - are you full read my comment ? a say about this

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It is, but it's ignored when passing an `OVERLAPPED` structure. That statement is correct in context.

Comment: The user is going to take your code and think that he has to use OVERLAPPED in this way. I don't think it's helpful to this asker. What he needs is to be told to check return values, and read the file sequentially with no need for any pointer setting. Of course, the question doesn't ask that, but that knowledge came from his previous question. So not really your fault that the asker asked the wrong question. Previous question said, "how can I read a 5MB file in 5 separate 1MB chunks". That's what he really wants to do.

Comment: @Cyclone Probably SetFilePointer succeeds, but is superseded by the offset in OVERLAPPED

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - are in my answer something wrong/incorrect ? I not take to account level of OP

Comment: Where's the clear explanation of the basics? The asker is a total novice with not much clue. You did not explain anything. I'd expect to see coverage of error checking, why overlapped structure supersedes SetFilePointer, why file pointer setting not needed when reading sequentially.

Comment: Your answers are frequently like this, technically correct, but pitched at the wrong level, not explaining the basics, and often including gory implementation details, suggestions to use undocumented functions and so on.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: As the famous Raymond Chen once put it: *"[Be that someone](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110118-00/?p=11733)"*

Comment: @IInspectable on another day, but I'm about to get in a car for a few hours.... Sorry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - ok, I little update answer for add extra explanation